# How do I clear both with github readme?

Tags: image, github, markdown

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH0an.png)

(the issue is topic 2 should be under the image)

My readme code is this

```
## Topic

<img src="blank.jpg" align="left" alt="drawing" width="400"/>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has sur
  
## Topic 2
```

My issue is I want topic 2 to be under the image which could be done in html by using clear both under the text but unsure how to do this in github readme

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try by adding a line break.  `</br>`
For example:

```
<img src="blank.jpg" align="left" alt="drawing" width="400"/>
</br>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has sur
  
## Topic 2
```

Comment: The `br` element has a mandatory start tag and a forbidden end tag. It's `<br>` not `</br>`

Comment: A line break won't work for floating content anyway.

Comment: Even if it would work (it still won't) you put it in the wrong place!

Comment: Paste that code in any md editor and check it out.

Comment: OK. Fine. (Opens Markdown Pro. Pastes it in). Right. Confirmed. It **doesn't** work.